# converting object to string in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I've faced a problem converting an Object into String in flex . my object is mydropdown selecteditem and I want to convert it to string and show it on a label tag . I've tried ".toString()" and "as String" and "String()" but none of them worked . anyone has any experience with it ?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selectedItem object has *data* and *label* properties, depending on the data that you're supplying you'd want something like this:

```
mydropdown.selectedItem.label
```

Comment: didn't work . when I use mydropdown.selectedItem.label , it shows nothing .

Comment: Well it depends on the data that you're providing, using _data_ and _label_ is just convention.  Is there a labelField that is defined for your DropDownList?  In my example it would be labelField = "label".

Comment: thanks , that worked . my labelField="genre" and I used it like myDropDown.selectedItem.genre and it worked . thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If your "mydropdown selecteditem" is a class that you wrote yourself, you could create a toString() method in there and make it return something useful.

Comment: no . by mydropdown I meant the id of my DropDownList and it's selecteditem property